# RabbitTemplate-convertSendAndReceive() giving a "null" response

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am trying to write sender receiver program which will send request and wait for the reply until receiver process the request. But getting a "null" response when I call this method -convertSendAndReceive().

Answer (score 2):

Well, which reply are you going to get if your "receiver is not running"?

Anyway `RabbitTemplate` has `replyTimeout` option which is:

```
private static final long DEFAULT_REPLY_TIMEOUT = 5000;
```

yeah... by default.

Comment: Glad to hear! So, the best way to go is to accept my answer 

Comment: yes i have modified the default REPLY_TIMEOUT  to 60000 and it is waiting for response.

Comment: could you please help in this question as well 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37988739/not-able-to-process-response-received-from-template-convertsendandreceive